# The SDK location is inside studio install location

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

To update the android studio from 1.5 preview 2 to 2.2 preview 1, I have downloaded required zip the unzipped it and installed it and its working fine. Now I want to change the sdk path of it. My android studio installation path is E:\android-studio and I want to put sdk in this folder. Before it was in someother folder E:\folder\sdk and now when I am putting it in E\android-studio and setting sdk path in studio the error is title of the question. Is this a rule not to put sdk in installation folder? Should I keep the old sdk path as it is?

Comment: Yes, you'll probably need to put it somewhere _other than_ `E:\android-studio`, if android studio doesn't like the SDK being in the same directory.

Comment: thank you I think I will do that.. and one more thing I have observed is with new version 2.2 I am getting error in the same project I used to work in 1.5. It is regarding third party app... now what can be the catch here?

Comment: What is the error you're getting ? I'm afraid I probably don't know, though.

Comment: simply says cant resolve method